# java.lang.IllegalStateException when assessing ROOM database first time in app

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I have a couple applications which were using com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper to read in read-only databases (never updated during an application session). For some reason, I decided to refactor them to use ROOM.

All works correctly in my emulators and on the one Android phone that I have, but once released the apps are crashing frequently (maybe every time) for my users.  This is occurring at the first time in the app where my code is calling a database query.

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:138)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:9)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:400)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:4)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:2)
  at androidx.room.SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteCopyOpenHelper.java:13)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:2)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java)
  at com.XXX.YYY.model.bah.dao.BahDao_Impl.getInfoFromDatabase (BahDao_Impl.java:13)
  at com.XXX.YYY.model.MyClass.getInfoFromDatabase (MyClass.java:20)
  at com.XXX.YYY.controller.MyFragment$UpdateBahInfoTask.run (MyFragment.java:17)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

These are the first versions of these applications which are using ROOM, so I am not sure why the onUpgrade method is being called or if that is an indication where the issue lies.  I am kind of at a loss of where to go with this.  My use of these databases is very simple (e.g. just performing queries based on user actions).  I cannot replicate this on the emulators or actual device even when upgrading the old app to the new version using adb.

I did start the database version at the same number used by the Sqlite version of the apps, so that is the only thing that maybe could be causing this.

```
@Database(entities = {Table1.class, Table2.class, Table3.class}, exportSchema = true, version = 14)
public abstract class BahDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

  public abstract BahDao bahDao();
}
```

I am thinking that I will:

1. increment the database versions
2. add a call to .addMigrations(MIGRATION_14_15) when I build the database

```
//Used for creating singleton  
private MyClass(Context context) {

    mBahDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, BahDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME_ROOM)
        .createFromAsset(DATABASE_ASSET_FULL_PATH)
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_14_15)
        .build();
  }
```

3. And just put a stub for that migration class that will do nothing (as nothing in the database is changing)

```
  static final Migration MIGRATION_14_15 = new Migration(14, 15) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
      // Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
      Log.d(TAG, "MIGRATION_14_15 Called");
    }
  };
```

UPDATE: The above three steps had no effect as the new version of the app is still crashing with this same error.

UPDATE2: Replaced call to addMigrations(MIGRATION_14_15) with call to  fallbackToDestructiveMigration().  As my database created from createFromAsset() is never changed by the app, I could care less if Android balks during some ill conceived migration.  The JavaDoc states the below which is fine with my design as the database in my assets folder is always what the app should be using (in regards to tables and data):

*If the database was create from an asset or a file then Room will try to use the same file to re-create the database, otherwise this will delete all of the data in the database tables managed by Room.*

Will see what happens

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IllegalStateException occurs when your application invokes a method at inappropriate times. Looking at your stack trace. the issues maybe arising from these areas.
....

`at com.XXX.YYY.model.bah.dao.BahDao_Impl.getInfoFromDatabase (BahDao_Impl.java:13)`

`at com.XXX.YYY.model.MyClass.getInfoFromDatabase (MyClass.java:20)`

`at com.XXX.YYY.controller.MyFragment$UpdateBahInfoTask.run (MyFragment.java:17)`

You should check those methods in model and controller files in your code.

Answer (score 0):

So I made that change to add a call to fallbackToDestructiveMigration() when building the database, and that appears to prevent the crashes.  So the relevant part of my singleton which builds the database is below:

```
    mBahDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, BahDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME_ROOM)
        .createFromAsset(DATABASE_ASSET_FULL_PATH)
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .build();
```

Now, I have no idea why this works or what the underlying problem was.  To restate:

- This was the first version of my application which used a Room database.  Previously I used com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper to copy the database from the asset folder and use the copy as a read-only database in my app.
- Therefore, Room should not be doing any method calling related to migrations.
- I suspect that Room was having some kind of issue with the old database on a user's phone which was copied over by com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper in a previous version of my app.
- Based on the above, I suspect that this is some odd Android bug, but not many app devs are likely in the scenario that I am in regards to the refactoring to Room.
- Luckily, I could care less about what Room did during its migration processing as the database provided in my apk is the one I want to use (also not modified by the app) and any database updates are always provided in a subsequent apk.
- No matter what scenarios I created in regards to what was on the emulator/phone before I installed the new app, I could never get the app to crash (like my users were seeing) when using an emulator or an old Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a `new Migration(14, 15)` when the `@Database` annotation still says `version = 14`. It shouldn't throw an `IllegalStateException` when the `@Database` annotation would be `version = 15`. Generally speaking, when the **current** version is `14`, it makes no sense to migrate to `15` (as `14` currently is the latest version in existence). Also see [Understanding migrations with Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929).

Comment: To clarify, I added that MIGRATION_14_15 in a subsequent version of the app when I also changed the database version to 15 (with no changes to the actual DB).  That was one troubleshooting attempt. The app crashed before that change (with DB version =14 and no MIGRATION_14_15) and after (with DB version=15 and with the MIGRATION_14_15 call).  So it had no effect.